# Can't fix static linkage issue by adding static to function prototype

Tags: c++, ros, catkin

I am trying to get GPS data from `"/mavros/global_position/global"` using the following codes below:

**This is a header file:**

```
#pragma once

#include <sensor_msgs/NavSatFix.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>


class Localization{
public:
    // Functions

    void receiver(const sensor_msgs::NavSatFixConstPtr& data);

    // Constructors
    Localization(ros::NodeHandle);
private:
    // Data types
    double latitiude;
    double longitude;
    double altitude;
    const std::string topic {"/mavros/global_position/global"};
};

void Localization::receiver(const sensor_msgs::NavSatFixConstPtr& fix){
    if (fix->status.status == sensor_msgs::NavSatStatus::STATUS_NO_FIX) {
        ROS_INFO("No fix.");
        return;
    }
    latitiude = (*fix).latitude;
    longitude = (*fix).longitude;
    altitude = (*fix).altitude;

    ROS_INFO("Latitude: %f | Longitude: %f | Altitude: %f", latitiude, longitude, altitude);
};

Localization::Localization(ros::NodeHandle nh){
    ros::Subscriber location = nh.subscribe(topic, 1, receiver);
};
```

When I tried to build the entire program using `catkin_make` I get the following error:

```
 error: cannot declare member function ‘void Localization::receiver(const NavSatFixConstPtr&)’ to have static linkage [-fpermissive]
 static void Localization::receiver(const sensor_msgs::NavSatFixConstPtr& fix){
```

I searched online and found a rather simple solution to this issue which is to add static to the `void receiver` function prototype. However, if I do so, I can not also access the private class members.

I used changed the constructor definition to:

```
Localization::Localization(ros::NodeHandle nh){
    ros::Subscriber location = nh.subscribe(topic, 1, Localization::receiver, this);
};
```

This gave me a similar error:

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘void Localization::receiver(const NavSatFixConstPtr&)’
     ros::Subscriber location = nh.subscribe(topic, 1, Localization::receiver, this);
                                                                                   ^
/home/kannachan/drone/src/quantum_drone/scripts/missions/gps.h:11:9: note: declared here
    void receiver(const sensor_msgs::NavSatFixConstPtr& data);
```

Comment: The error message mentions `static void Localization::receiver` but there is no such thing in the code.

Comment: Try this: `ros::Subscriber location = nh.subscribe(topic, 1, &Localization::receiver, this);`

Comment: @PatricioLoncomilla I received a similar error but I think it got pass the void function prototype and definition. I will edit my post with the error that I got from using your solution.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Sorry, I pasted the error when I wrote `static void` instead of `void`. I used the solution that @PatricioLoncomillia but I received another error. I'd edited my post with the error that I've received.

Comment: Try to use `ros::Subscriber location = nh.subscribe(topic, 1, &Localization::receiver, this);`, and not `ros::Subscriber location = nh.subscribe(topic, 1, Localization::receiver, this);` (the & symbol is missing). I hope this solution would work.

Comment: @PatricioLoncomilla My apologies, didn't notice it at all. Your solution worked well and `catkin_make` was able to build my program. Appreciate it!